# How many times has an NHL team completed a playoffs sweep without trailing?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl, postseason, stanley-cup

The Montreal Canadiens swept the Winnipeg Jets in the second round of the 2020-21 playoffs. The Canadiens pulled off the sweep without ever trailing in the series.

How many times an NHL team swept a playoff series without ever trailing?

Comment: I doubt I'll have time to look at this anytime soon; but it's really not much harder than what I did for the Comebacks question, with [this code](https://github.com/snoopy369/Sports.SE/blob/master/HockRef%20Parse%20Comebacks.py)... would be some work to get the playoffs instead of regular season pages, but otherwise not that hard.

Comment: I'm gonna scraper if I don't get an answer soon anyway, will take a look at your answer